# How to translate this equation into physicist's notation?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, tensors

How to translate this equation into physicist's notation, i.e. tensors with indices?
$$\left\langle R_{N}\left(u,v\right)w,z\right\rangle =\left\langle R_{M}\left(u,v\right)w,z\right\rangle +\left\langle II\left(u,z\right),II\left(v,w\right)\right\rangle -\left\langle II\left(u,w\right),II\left(v,z\right)\right\rangle $$
This equation is from the Wikipedia article about [second fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form), last equation of that article. $R_N$ is curvature tensor of a manifold embedded in another manifold with curvature tensor $R_M$. $II$ is the second fundamental form.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a standard way to deal with submanifolds in index notation. Is there some king of notation in particular that your interested in, such as a slice chart with different types of indices, or separate coordinate charts for $M$ and $N$?